Indicator Menu event on mouse release in Gnome Shell Extension
I used gnome-extensions create --interactive to create the Indicator example app and can add a MenuItem and get an event when it's clicked.
How can i get an event on mouse press and release instead of only on activate. Also clicking should not close the menu.
